# Fix macro code to display a different range

Tags: vba, excel

I am sure this is a rather simple question for majority of you but I have this code

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("L1").Value2
```

This allows me to take the contents of L1 and paste it as a static value in the next available cell in column B. I now want to use this code for a different "range." That range being the combination of the text of two cells into the new one. I use the following code to do just that

```
With ActiveCell
    .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(L1,N1)"
    .Cells = .Value
    .WrapText = False
```

Except that it will always post the new value into the active cell and it will not register that the value should be pasted in the next available cell Column A. I have tried replacing the first two lines of the code with the following...

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("L1&N1").Value2
```

and

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("=CONCATENATE(L1,N1)").Value2
```

and

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(L1,N1)".Value2
```

I'm not too sure what to try next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but are currently breaking a few syntax conventions.

Purpose: To concatenate the values in L1 and N1 into a string and put it into the next available cell in column A.

The first one should be written closer to:

```
With ActiveSheet
   .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("L1").Value2 & .Range("N1").Value2
end with
```

Skipping the second one, the third should be:

```
With ActiveSheet
   .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(L1,N1)"
end with
'or,
With ActiveSheet
   .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
      application.evaluate("CONCATENATE(L1,N1)")
end with
```

In the latter two examples, the first puts an actual formula into the cell and the second evaluates the result of what the formula would return and puts the result into the cell.

Additional cell properties could be addressed by referencing the cell to be dealt with in a nested [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
With ActiveSheet
    with .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .value = application.evaluate("CONCATENATE(L1,N1)")
        .wraptext = false
    end with
end with
```

Take another look at the link I provided for hte With ... End With documentation. The above starts with the ActiveSheet then with the next blank cell in column A. Everything you apply inside this second With ... End With will happen to that cell and that cell only.

Comment: Should I just replace the first two lines of my original code with the last code you provided??

Comment: Any of the three examples should be adequate for what you are trying to achieve. Pick the one that makes the most sense to you and implement it.

Comment: Well, the third one is perfect, its just that the next two lines ".Cells = .Value
    .WrapText = False" at the end of my code, are there to make the text not wrapped. Unfortunately, the new code doesn't like me adding those two lines under it to prevent the text from being wrapped.

Comment: It is hard to read from a comment as there are no line breaks but it looks like you are applying the With ... End With properly. See above.

Comment: ooh okay that makes much more sense. Two with/end with.. That helps a ton. Thank you for all the help, Jeeped